# Pandas: Aggregate each column into a comma separated list without duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

**Problem:**

I have a large CSV file which looks something like this:

```
A  B   C     D    ...
1  dog black NULL ...
1  dog white NULL ...
1  dog black NULL ...
2  cat red   NULL ...
...
```

Now I want to "group by" column `A` and aggregate each remaining column to a comma separated list without duplicates. The solutions should look something like this:

```
A  B   C             D    ...
1  dog black, white  NULL ...
2  cat red           NULL ...
...
```

Since the names and numbers of columns in the CSV may change, I prefer a solution without hard coded names.

**Used Approach:**

I tried the package `pandas` with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("C://input.csv", sep=';')
data = data.where((pd.notnull(data)), None)
data_group = data.groupby(['A']).agg(lambda x: set(x))
data_group.to_csv("C://result.csv", sep=';')
```

The `set` operator does exactly what I want. However, the resulting CSV looks like this:

```
A  B       C                   D      ...
1  {'dog'} {'black', 'white'}  {None} ...
2  {'cat'} {'red'}             {None} ...
...
```

I don't want the `{}` and `''` in my export and also column `D`should be empty and not containing the word `None`.

**Question:**

Am I on the right track, or is there a much more elegant way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`join` the set with comma:

```
df.groupby('A', as_index=False).agg(lambda x: ', '.join(set(x.dropna())))

#   A    B             C D
#0  1  dog  white, black  
#1  2  cat           red
```

Comment: The solution looks promising. However, if I run your code, it removes column D entirely and all columns containing numeric values.

Comment: Try `df.groupby('A', as_index=False).agg(lambda x: ', '.join(set(x.astype(str))))` if you want to join numeric columns as well.

Comment: Holy cow, I have no idea how, but it does exactly what I want. Thank you very much.